# How to copy many images fast with Python

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-asyncio, shutil, file-copying

I have a task to move millions of images from one network share drive to another in Windows. These are not very large images there are just many of them. I have 900,000 directories to move each containing 1-10 images. My goal is to leverage the OS to achieve maximum concurrency and I think asyncio might help me achieve this since most of the time will be spent waiting for network io. This is a snippet of what I have so far but it still seems too slow as it takes me 5 mins to move around 250MB of images. Here's a sample of what I've got so far, I'm not completely convinced my implementation is sound.

```
async def iter_copytree(src, dst):
    try:
        shutil.copytree(src, dst)
        return []
    except Exception e:
        return [e]

async def iter_dircmp(src, dst):
    dcmp = filecmp.dircmp(src, dst)
    if dcmp.funny_files or dcmp.diff_files:
         return [dcmp]
    return []

async def iter_rmtree(src):
    try:
        shutil.rmtree(src)
        return []
    except Exception as e:
        return [e]

async def iter_move(src, dst):
    if await iter_copytree(src, dst):
        return
    if await iter_dircmp(src, dst):
        return
    await iter_rmtree(src)

async def move_files(src_root, dst_root, file_names):
    tasks = [iter_move(os.path.join(src_root, i), ...) for i in file_names]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(move_files(...))
```

Comment: Why do you think that using multiple threads would speed up this kind of application?  If there is one disk where the files come from, and one other disk they go to, and one network connection joining them, I would expect the application performance to be strongly limited by the OS and the network. (I could be wrong, of course).  Have you tried a simple test program, say: transfer 1000 files in a single thread and then split that same work between two threads?  Can you see any performance difference?

Comment: The asyncio lib is threadless, if done right it should queue up my blocking calls which are picked up in the event loop when they return.

Comment: So if it's not multithreaded, how does an event loop help the file transfer go faster?  I'm still thinking you're limited by the computing environment and not the speed or structure of your python program.  How long does it take to move 250 MB worth of these small image files by dragging them from one PC to another with Windows Explorer?  My experience is that moving a lot of little files is painfully slow, no matter how you do it.  Zipping the files may help.

Comment: All the i/o calls are blocking, so I don't want to do them one at a time because the cpu would be idle most of the time waiting on the network.

Comment: That's the point I'm trying to make.  If (1) the CPU is idle waiting for the network, and (2) your application requires the network, then you can't speed up your application by using the CPU more efficiently. Threading, multiprocessing or event loops can only make a difference if they allow idle cycles of the CPU to do something useful.  As I write this comment, my CPU is mostly idle waiting for me to type the next key.  I don't see that as a problem, because the CPU is not the thing that's preventing me from finishing faster.

Answer (score 1):

rsync, xcopy, robocopy
multiple highly scalable solutions before you'd need to write a line of code